# How to determine if a linux shared library was implicitly loaded, or explicitly loaded (using dlopen)

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, dlopen

I have a shared library on linux, and I want to be able to determine if my library was implicitly loaded (by the linker), or explicitly loaded (by dlopen).

On windows, DllMain provides this information:

> If fdwReason is DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, lpvReserved is NULL for dynamic
>   loads and non-NULL for static loads.

I know about `__attribute__ ((constructor)` in gcc, but that does not provide the information about whether the library was implicitly or explicitly loaded.

Is there a way to determine this information? I've looked at dl_iterate_phdr, but I don't see anything in there that would help, but perhaps I'm missing something.